# How to save TextBoxes Values into a multiline text file

Tags: c#, text, save, multiline

Please see below

My form having multiple text boxes

[image]

I want to save the values into a one text file having a multiline text file.

But my code doesn't seem to work. It saves the values as a one string only.
I would like to save it as per row

Ex. What i want to achieve

[image]

Please see below my code

```
   SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

        save.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(save.FileName));



                write.Write(X1TB.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, @" \n "));
                write.Write(X2TB.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, @" \n "));
                write.Write(X3TB.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, @" \n "));
                write.Write(X4TB.Text);
                write.Write(X5TB.Text);
                write.Write(X6TB.Text);
                write.Write(X7TB.Text);
                write.Write(X8TB.Text);
                write.Write(X9TB.Text);
                write.Write(X10TB.Text);
                write.Write(X11TB.Text);
                write.Write(X12TB.Text);
                write.Write(X13TB.Text);
                write.Write(X14TB.Text);
                write.Write(X15TB.Text);
                write.Write(X16TB.Text);
                write.Write(X17TB.Text);
                write.Write(X18TB.Text);
                write.Write(X19TB.Text);
                write.Write(X20TB.Text);

                write.Dispose();

                MessageBox.Show("The file is now saved!", "Successful!");
```

Thank you in advance for those who will help.

Comment: Try removing the @ here `Environment.NewLine, " \n "));` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try using Carriage Return and Line Feed `"\r\n"`

Comment: have you tried `write.WriteLine`?

Comment: @TahreemIqbal i tried but it showed this System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 1
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 2
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 3

Comment: @Fabulous I tried this "write.Write(X4TB.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " \n "));" but nothing happned they're still saving in a one line.

Comment: Have you tried what @Vj- suggested?

Comment: @visualstudio You mean it didn't know textbox values at all? That is odd.

Comment: I figured it out guys i used "write.Write(X20TB.Text + "\n");" i add the \n in my code to enter a new line

Comment: @TahreemIqbal he probably didn't `WriteLine` the text property but the control and the ToString was sent across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    write.WriteLine(X1TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X2TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X3TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X4TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X5TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X6TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X7TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X8TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X9TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X10TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X11TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X12TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X13TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X14TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X15TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X16TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X17TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X18TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X19TB.Text);
    write.WriteLine(X20TB.Text);
```

Comment: i have done this and it worked    write.Write(X20TB.Text + "\n");

Comment: Yea but you have WriteLIne mthod for the same according to my advice you should use WriteLine instead this.@visualstudio

Comment: I followed your advise mate

Answer (score 0):

You can streamline the code if these are the only text boxes you are working with as follows:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int index = 1; index <= 20; index++)
{
    var tb = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find($"X{index}TB", true).FirstOrDefault;
    sb.AppendLine(tb.Text);
}

// Save the contents of the file.
var write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(save.FileName));
write.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my working way**

> `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\TextFile1.txt", new string[] { "1",
>   "2", "3", "4" });`

**It looks like**

`1

2

3

4`